# Identifier cout is undefined..and others

Tags: c++, cout, getline, unordered-map

I don't understand what's going on. I compiled the program a few times and everything was going fine. But since I inserted `#include <unordered_map>`, I'm getting errors such "undeclared identifier on cout...no instance of overloaded function for getline". I'm using Visual Studio 10. 
Also if someone could tell me how to properly initialize `unordered_map`, that would be great.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

unordered_map<string, dictionary * > Mymap;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string option;
    string pass;
    int choice=0;

    unsigned char hash[20];
    char hex_str[41];

    while(choice!=4)
    {
        cout<< "Select an option:"<< endl;
        cout<<"1. Basic Hashing"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Load Dictionary"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Decrypt"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Exit" <<endl;

        getline(cin,option);
        stringstream(option) >> choice;

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter a sample password"<<endl;
            getline(cin,pass);
            const char * c= pass.c_str();
            sha1::calc(c,pass.length(), hash);
            sha1::toHexString(hash,hex_str);
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Hashed: "<< hex_str<<endl;
        }
        else if(choice ==2)
        {
            string answer;
            cout<<"Would you like to use the default dictionary file(d8.txt). Press y or n"<<endl;
            getline(cin,answer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` Please stop doing this.

Comment: the weird part is that only the 1st cout gives me errors, but all the getlines show up as errors

Comment: i tried taking it out and using std, but i got errors when i tried to call std::sha1 @nicolBolas

Comment: @user1665569: There is no `std::sha1`. `std` is a C++ namespace that contains things defined by the C++ standard library. It's not a thing you stick in front of *everything*.

Comment: that file has the includes that I need tho...

Comment: @nicolBolas. i tried taking out the std and now it tells me namespace std has no members cout...

Comment: BTW, what is your `dictionary` type?

Comment: struct dictionary{
 string word;
 char * hash;
 char *hex;
}

Comment: And where is `sha1` defined?  I can't seem to find it.

Comment: it's a namespace, that is on a different file

Comment: it seemes like the problem is on my struct.h file.after i deleted it, everythin was giving me pch warning..

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) regarding `using namespace std` and why not to use it.  The below code still does not compile, but only has errors regarding the missing definition for `sha1` which you probably have somewhere.  (And I added the struct def right above `Mymap` just to reduce errors).

Regarding errors, usually C++ compiler will give you a meaningful error description at the first one it encounters, but thereafter, things might get strange, so you fix them one at a time to start getting some clarity.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef struct dictionary{ std::string word; char * hash; char *hex; } a_dictionary;
std::unordered_map<std::string, a_dictionary * > Mymap;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string option;
    std::string pass;
    int choice=0;

    unsigned char hash[20];
    char hex_str[41];

    while(choice!=4)
    {
        std::cout<< "Select an option:"<< std::endl;
        std::cout<<"1. Basic Hashing"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"2. Load Dictionary"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"3. Decrypt"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"4. Exit" <<std::endl;

        getline(std::cin,option);
        std::stringstream(option) >> choice;

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            std::cout<<"Please enter a sample password"<<std::endl;
            getline(std::cin,pass);
            const char * c= pass.c_str();
            sha1::calc(c,pass.length(), hash);
            sha1::toHexstd::string(hash,hex_str);
            std::cout<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Hashed: "<< hex_str<<std::endl;
        }
        else if(choice ==2)
        {
            std::string answer;
            std::cout<<"Would you like to use the default dictionary file(d8.txt). Press y or n"<<std::endl;
            getline(std::cin,answer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```